# c# how to get keydown and button click to do the same thing?

Tags: c#, calculator

I am new to C#.I am learning to make a calculator just like ms windows calculator.the buttons work when i click it, but I want the numpad to work too. Suppose the user types '0', it should be the same as if he clicked the 0 button on my gui. here is my button click event for 0.

```
private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkifequa();
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";
        }
```

how do i get the keydown to work?

EDIT

here is the full source. It was wriiten by some guy on youtube, i am only modifying and trying to learn .Please point any mistakes and also suggest better ways.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool plus = false;
        bool minus = false;
        bool into = false;
        bool divd = false;
        bool equa = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkifequa();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkifequa();

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
    }

    private void checkifequa()
    {
        if (equa)
            textBox1.Text = "";
        equa = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkifequa();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "2";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkifequa();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "3";
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkifequa();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "4";
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkifequa();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "5";
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkifequa();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "6";
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkifequa();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "7";
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkifequa();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "8";
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkifequa();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "9";
    }

    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkifequa();
        if(textBox1.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
        textBox1.Text=textBox1.Text+".";
        }

    }

    private void plusminus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains("-"))
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(0, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "-" + textBox1.Text;
        }
    }

    private void plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        { 
            plus = true;
            textBox1.Tag = textBox1.Text;
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }

    }

    private void equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        equa = true;

        if (plus)
        {
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Tag) + Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = dec.ToString();

        }
        if (minus)
        {
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Tag) - Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = dec.ToString();

        }
        if (into)
        {
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Tag) * Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = dec.ToString();

        }
        if (divd)
        {
            decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Tag) / Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = dec.ToString();

        }
    }

    private void substract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (minus)
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                minus = true;
                textBox1.Tag = textBox1.Text;
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
    }

    private void multiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            into = true;
            textBox1.Tag = textBox1.Text;
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void divide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            divd = true;
            textBox1.Tag = textBox1.Text;
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        plus = minus = into = divd = equa = false;
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Tag = "";

    }




    void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57)
        {
            switch (e.KeyChar)
            {
                case (char)48:
                    button0.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case (char)49:
                    button1.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case (char)50:
                    button2.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case (char)51:
                    button3.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case (char)52:
                    button4.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case (char)53:
                    button5.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case (char)54:
                    button6.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case (char)55:
                    button7.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case (char)56:
                    button8.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case (char)57:
                    button9.PerformClick();
                    break;

            }

        }  
    }


}

}

Answer (score 1):

check the PreviewKeyDown event of window and do some thing like this

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
{
   // Do what you want to do.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the same event handler for all buttons with the same code/functionality, like:

```
buttonZero.Click += numberButton_Click;
buttonOne.Click += numberButton_Click;
...

buttonPlus.Click += numberButton_Click;
buttonMinus.Click += numberButton_Click;
...

private void numberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   checkifequa();
   var numButton = sender as Button;
   if(numButton != null)
      textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + numButton.Text; // supposing your num buttons have only the number as text (otherwise you could use the Tag property of buttons)
}

private void operatorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   checkifequa();
   var operatorButton = sender as Button;
   if(operatorButton != null)
      textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + operatorButton .Text; // supposing your operator buttons have only the operator as text (otherwise you could use the Tag property of button)
}
// ...
```

For the keyboard events, as suggested by cre-johnny07:
you could handle previewKeyDown event or KeyDown event and do something like:

```
private void parentControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0)
        this.buttonZero.PerformClick();
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
        this.buttonOne.PerformClick();
    // and so on... 
}
```

In this way, you will also have a nice button-click effect when typing on the numPad...

Comment: thanks, i found somethin similar on MSDN for keyboard event , i have edited my code, plz check again

Comment: Your solution is basically the same as mine for the keyboard part, I only suggest you to use KeyDown event and KeyCode because is more readable than char casting.

For the click events part, my suggestion is the same as before, i.e. just add the same handler to every buttons with the same functionality (it is possible also in the designer) , this lead to less code ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do is make both the mouse clicking event and the keydown event point to the same thing. If you go in your control properties under events, select the same event for both keydown and mouseclick. Just add an "if" statement in your code to check who's calling it.

From my experience, the structure of the program becomes way more neater.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the "business logic" out of the click/key-down handler. Also, I would store the data in private properties instead of the Tag of the TextBox. I've left out the validation code which you normally would have.

```
private string FirstNumber { get; set; }
private string SecondNumber { get; set; }
private bool IsSecondNumberBeingEntered { get; set; }

private Operation SelectedOperation { get; set;}
private enum Operation
{
    Add,
    Subtract,
    Multiply,
    Divide
}

private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AddNumber(0);
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";
}

// Etc.

// In PreviewKeyDown:
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode == Keys.D0)
{
    this.AddNumber(0);
}

private void AddNumber(int number)
{
    if (IsSecondNumberBeingEntered)
    {
        SecondNumber += number.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        FirstNumber += number.ToString();
    }
}

private decimal Calculate()
{
    switch (SelectedOperation)
    {
        case Operation.Add:
            return Convert.ToDecimal(FirstNumber) + Convert.ToDecimal(SecondNumber);
        case Operation.Subtract:
            return Convert.ToDecimal(FirstNumber) - Convert.ToDecimal(SecondNumber);
        // etc.
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```